# How to print number of particular columns in shell script?

Tags: unix, sed, awk

I have a text file temp1 and say it has more than 20 columns and it has numerical values like as follows,

```
1,0,3,0,5........,
1,0,5,0,8........,
3,0,6,0,3........,
5,0,6,0,4........,
.................,
```

I want to remove the columns which has the total(sum) of zero and i need to redirect remaining columns to the new file

ie : for example as above 2nd and 4th columns have the total of zero so i need to remove 2nd and 4 th column and redirect it to separate file .

can any one help me pls?

Comment: If line 1 field 2 had value `-1` instead of zero, and line 2 field 2 had value `1` instead of zero, should column 2 be printed? I assume not since the sum for that column would still be zero but please clarify, preferably by updating your input/output above to show that case.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat file
1,0,3,0,5
1,0,5,0,8
3,0,6,0,3
5,0,6,0,4

$ awk -f tst.awk file
1,3,5
1,5,8
3,6,3
5,6,4

$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{ FS="," }
{
    for (j=1;j<=NF;j++) {
        val[NR,j] = $j
        sum[j] += val[NR,j]
    }
}
END {
    for (i=1;i<=NR;i++) {
        ofs = ""
        for (j=1;j<=NF;j++) {
            if (sum[j]) {
                printf "%s%s",ofs,val[i,j]
                ofs = FS
            }
        }
        print ""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use awk: (the following is *ugly* but I hope readable. That's the goal. I let better awkist enhance/reduce it further)

If the data is in file `/path/to/zefile`:

```
awk -F',' '  
      FNR==NR { for (col=1;col<=NF;col++)
                   { if ($col != 0) 
                        {wewantthiscolumn[col]=1 } 
                   }
                next
              }

              { for (col=1;col<=NF;col++) 
                   { if (wewantthiscolumn[col]==1) 
                        { printf ("%s,",$col) } 
                   }
                print "" 
              }' /path/to/zefile /path/to/zefile | sed -e 's/,$//'
```

The idea: we launch awk on /path/to/zefile /path/to/zefile (hence, it read is twice).

On the first pass, we create a "wewantthiscolumn" array. This array contains "1" as soon as that column has something different from 0. The "next" ensure we only do this bit when FNR (=Number of Rows in the CURRENT file) == NR (=total number of rows), which is true only on the first pass.

On the second pass (hence we go directly to the 2nd {  } as now NR>FNR) : we only display the column value `$col` which has a corresponding `wewantthiscolumn(col)==1`, and followed by a ","  (so there is a little problem: the last col will have a "," after it)

Then we pass this through sed to get rid of the ",$" bit.

I am not sure there is not a very better way : can awk delete a field? so it could delete field col on the 2nd pass? Then it would be much easier to print the resulting $0, setting `OFS=','` to have them separated with `,` ...

This would make the 2nd pass:

```
 awk -F',' '  
      FNR==NR { for (col=1;col<=NF;col++)
                   { if ($col != 0) 
                        {wewantthiscolumn[col]=1 } 
                   }
                next
              }

              { for (col=1;col<=NF;col++) 
                   { if (wewantthiscolumn[col]==0) 
                        $col="DELETETHIS"
                   }
                gensub(",DELETETHIS","",g)
                gensub("DELETETHIS,","",g)
                print $0 
              }' /path/to/zefile /path/to/zefile
```

I didn't want to assume no columns could be empty, hence I use "DELETETHIS" to make sure I only delete relevant fields... But this means the 1st way is in fact simpler ^^  : only print the fields you need, and then get rid of the "," at the end of line.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using `awk`. Run like:

```
awk -f ./script.awk file{,}
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    FS=","
}

FNR==NR {
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        if ($i != 0) {
            a[i]
        }
    }
    next
}

{
    for(j=1;j<=NF;j++) {
        if (j in a) {
            printf "%s%s", $j, (j==NF ? RS : FS)
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, here's the one-liner:

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i != 0) a[i]; next } { for(j=1;j<=NF;j++) if (j in a) printf "%s%s", $j, (j==NF ? RS : FS) }' filex{,}
```

Contents of `file`:

```
1,0,3,0,5,0
1,0,5,0,8,1
3,0,6,0,3,2
5,0,6,0,4,5
```

Results:

```
1,3,5,0
1,5,8,1
3,6,3,2
5,6,4,5
```

Comment: I was going to steal your `printf "%s%s", $j, (j==NF ? RS : FS)` for my solution as I like the idea but then I realized it'd mean that if the last column has a zero sum then it wouldn't print the ending newline so every line would get concatenated so it won't work in this particular case. Thanks for the idea for next time though.

Comment: AH, now I remember what was bothering me about this solution - it will print columns that have `-1` in a field of record 1 and `1` in the same field in record 2 since neither of those have the value zero, but their sum is zero and so that column should presumably be removed.

Answer (score 0):

A solution using python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def transpose(grid):
    return zip(*grid)

def removeBlankRows(grid):
    return [list(row) for row in grid if any(map(int,row))]

grid = []
with open("input.csv") as fd:
    for line in fd:
        grid.append(line.strip().split(','))

data = removeBlankRows(transpose(removeBlankRows(transpose(grid))))

for i in data:
    print ",".join(i)
```

input:

```
1,0,3,0,5
1,0,5,0,8
3,0,6,0,3
5,0,6,0,4
```

output:

```
1,3,5
1,5,8
3,6,3
5,6,4
```

input:

```
1,0,3,0,5
1,0,5,0,8
3,0,6,0,3
5,0,6,1,4
```

output:

```
1,3,0,5
1,5,0,8
3,6,0,3
5,6,1,4
```

Comment: Hi all thanx for the update unfortunately my system got crashed its working fine.